# How to update a makefile variable based on command line input?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have defined a variable 'ABC = 0' in the makefile. Now when the makefile is run, the user is asked a question 'What type of program is it?', if the user enters 'pq', then update makefile variable 'ABC' to 1, else keep as it is.

Comment: Do you know how to write a shell script that asks a question, receives user input, then prints something?

Comment: Yes, just a read statement with a question string, and then echo the read variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make is not designed for user interaction, but it can delegate that task to a script.

Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo What type of program is it?
read

if [ "$REPLY" = pq ]; then
    echo 1
else
    echo 0
fi
```

Make can execute this script, collect the output and assign it to a variable. The only trick is that it will collect *all* of the output, so whatever doesn't belong (e.g. "What type of program is it") should be removed from the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read

if [ "$REPLY" = pq ]; then
    echo 1
else
    echo 0
fi
```

and handled by the makefile:

```
$(info  What type of program is it?)
ABC := $(shell ./ask.bsh)
```